# Displaying a Current User (Angular and Firebase)

Tags: angular, firebase, bootstrap-4

Below are my lines of code, I do not have an error but the current username is not displaying on the browser and the pages under the dropdown are not showing on the broswer.

I created a Navbar that has a dropdown list only to be shown to logged in user, this was showing before and after I implemented the Login using Google provider. Login also works perfectly but after using the *ngIf and the async pipe to personalize the login, I could not see the drop down menu and after login nothing happens. See my code below.

**Navbar.component.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { AngularFireAuth } from '@angular/fire/compat/auth';
import firebase from 'firebase/compat/app';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable'

@Component({
  selector: 'bs-navbar',
  templateUrl: './bs-navbar.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./bs-navbar.component.css']
})
export class BsNavbarComponent  {
  currentUser$: Observable<firebase.User> | undefined;
  currentUser: any;

  constructor(private afAuth: AngularFireAuth) { 
    this.currentUser = afAuth.authState;
    }
  

  logout() {
    this.afAuth.signOut(); 
  }

}
```

**Login.component.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { AngularFireAuth} from '@angular/fire/compat/auth';
import firebase from 'firebase/compat/app';


@Component({
  selector: 'app-login',
  templateUrl: './login.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./login.component.css']
})
export class LoginComponent {

  constructor(private afAuth: AngularFireAuth) {  
    
  }


  login() {

      this.afAuth.signInWithRedirect( new firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider());
  }

}
```

**navbar.component.html**

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-dark bg-dark mb-4">
    <div class="container-fluid">
     <a class="navbar-brand" routerLink="/">HM</a>
       <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarCollapse" aria-controls="navbarCollapse" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
      </button>
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarCollapse">
        <ul class="navbar-nav me-auto mb-2 mb-md-0">
          <li class="nav-item">
     <a class="nav-link" routerLink="/wishlists">Wishlists</a>
          </li>
          <ng-template  #anonymousUser>
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" routerLink="/login">Login</a>
              </li>
          </ng-template>
            <li ngbDropdown placement *ngIf="currentUser$ | async as user; else anonymousUser" class="nav-item dropdown">
                <a ngbDropdownToggle class="nav-link dropdown toggle" id="dropdown01" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">{{ user.displayName }}</a> 
                <div ngbDropdownMenu class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdown01">
                    <a ngbDropdownItem class="dropdown-item" routerLink="/admin/houses">My Houses</a>
                    <a ngbDropdownItem class="dropdown-item" (click)="logout()"> Log out</a>
                </div>
            </li>
        </ul>
        <form class="d-flex">
          <input class="form-control me-2" type="search" placeholder="Search" aria-label="Search">
          <button class="btn btn-outline-success" type="submit">Search</button>
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
  </nav>
```

Comment: In the navbar.component.ts, you have not assigned a value for currentUser$. Instead, you have assigned a value for currentUser, of which I do not understand the purpose.

Comment: that was an oversight, I just corrected , I am new using Firebase , I still dont have a compilation error but the dropdown are not showing

Answer (score 0):

In your navbar.component.ts
remove the line currentUser$:Observable<firebase.User> | undefined;
and in place of currentUser:any use this

```
currentUser:Observable<firebase.User | null>
```

and also in html file make the **currentUser$ as currentUser** in your *ngIf
Try this and tell me
This should work